# How to wait for an action to complete?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm new to `react` and `redux` and have been exploring how it is different from `angular`.

I'm trying to do a simple login page and am not able to achieve what I want. Once I get the username and password from a login form, I submit it like below :

```
  submitHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = {
      name : this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password
    }
    this.props.authenticateUser(user);
    browserHistory.push('/home');
    this.setState({
      username:'',
      password:''
    })
  }
```

Here, `authenticateUser` is a function inside my reducer (shown below) which checks from an already existing user's list and then the state with a property `isAuthenticated` :

```
 case 'AUTHENTICATE_USER':
        var users = state.userslist;
        var payloadUser = action.payload;
        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            let user = users[i]
            if (user.name === payloadUser.name) {
                return {...state, isAuthenticated: true };
            }
        };
        return {...state, isAuthenticated: false };
```

Now in Angular, I would just wait for this call to finish and check whether this value is `true` or `false`, and navigate to the home page using `angular-router`.

But how would I achieve the same in `react`. I am using `react-router` in my sample application.

I tried to check `isAuthenticated` in my `submitHandler` function right below where I call `this.props.authenticateUser(user)` , but the problem is , `this.props.isAuthenticateUser` is not updated and returns `false`, which I have set as the `initialState` in my reducer.

Please tell me how I can check `isAuthenticated` after the `authenticateUser` function has called so that I can proceed with my homepage routing. Do I have to use a `promise` and wait for the state to be updated by `redux` and then check it again ?? *(I know react is a one way path and it doesn't work that way.)*

Also if my authentication fails, how do I show an error panel below my login form. I think using a component for the error panel which takes in `isAuthenticated` as input and checking if false in order to show *(ie. ngShow like in Angular.)* But I'm afraid that will not work as well, since my state will not be updated just in time.

I know that the render function will be called with any change in state. But I just can't wrap my head around React clearly.

**Edit**: For brevity, I have not provided the action creators and the full reducer above rather shown only the switch case operation for authenticate user. My app follows the original redux architecture with actions, reducers, containers, components and such.

**EDIT:** Github link [here](https://github.com/V1cHu/react-redux)

Comment: https://github.com/V1cHu/react-redux this url going to 404 page. can you please share the proper url

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I will try to explain briefly how data flow works in a Redux application:

1. The reducer should not be called directly from the component. Your call to authenticate user should be inside an action and that is what should be dispatched from the component.
2. When you define the action, you can give a property to define the type of action it is. For example, in this case, it could be `type: AUTHENTICATE_USER`
3. After the completion of the action, the redux store calls the reducer where with the current state and the action. Here, the redux state can be updated based on `action.type` (the second code snippet above)
4. **This is the most important part:** your component needs to have a `mapStateToProps` method which passes values from your Redux state as props into your component. So as the state changes, the props get updated and the component re-renders. To use `mapStateToProps`, you need to implement connect from the react-redux library. (https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

To achieve what you want, this is what I suggest:

1. In your component's `componentWillReceiveProps` method, checking for `props.isAuthenticated` and using `context.router.push()` to navigate if the user is authenticated.
2. Also having a check based on `props.isAuthenticated` in the component's `render` method to show the error message.

A few links which could be useful:

https://redux.js.org/basics/data-flow

https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Comment: I do have the mapStateToProps which is where I inject isAuthenticated, but the problem is I dunno when and how I should check after the action has been dispatched. Because checking isAuthenticated right after the call to isAuthenticated, gives me undefined. The state is not updated immediately.

Comment: In a properly set up Redux application, the state is updated as soon as you receive the response and the reducer is called. I might be able to help you more by looking at your code. Do you perhaps have it on Gihub?

Comment: I'm at work right now. Will push the code to github and will share you the link once I reach home.

Comment: I've edited the question with the link to the code. Please help.

Comment: I did just took a look at your code and I still stand by my two earlier suggestions. A `componentWillReceiveProps` method in your login-form.js component will track the changes to your props and you can redirect based on `props.isAuthenticated`. More info here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Thank u soo much for reviewing the code. Also did you see how I am calling authenticateUser. You have asked me to use dispatch.methodName , but since I have mapped this to props , I have used it from props. Is that right ??

Answer (score 2):

I prefer code like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated
  }
}

class Dashboard extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        { isAuthenticated ? (
          <div>
            <p>Hello</p>
          </div>
        ) : (
          Login()
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56899814/3850405

Addition to the answer from @Nupur. `componentWillReceiveProps()` is considered unsafe and the method name now is: `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()`

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Use `componentDidUpdate()` instead if you would like this approach, this method is not called for the initial render.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated ) {
        //perform code here
    }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate